# Non accessible value in Mongo document

Tags: mongodb

In a MongoDB stream search like this:

```
Model
    .find({_id:"5682c7d9f8c6ea51c437e9a2"})
    .stream()
    .on('data', function(doc){
        console.log(doc);
        console.log(doc.downloadAt, doc.deliveredAt);
        ...
    });
```

The first `console.log()` return the object; like that:

```
{
_id: 5682c7d9f8c6ea51c437e9a2,
__t: 'couponHistory',
downloadAt: Fri Jan 01 2016 14:32:08 GMT-0600 (CST),
deliveredAt: Fri Jan 01 2016 14:31:44 GMT-0600 (CST),
__v: 0,
code: '0W087Z0V',
campaignId: 567ad792f8c6ea51c437e963,
redeemAt: Sat Jan 23 2016 21:44:48 GMT-0600 (CST),
updateAt: Mon Dec 21 2015 06:14:07 GMT-0600 (CST),
createdAt: Mon Dec 21 2015 06:14:07 GMT-0600 (CST),
delivered: true,
redeem: true
}
```

And the weird part, is the result of the second `console.log()`. I can see the value of `deliveredAt` but not of the `downloadAt`:

```
undefined Fri Jan 01 2016 14:31:44 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

In my collection, `downloadAt` is not a mandatory field, but in this case, the object contains a value

Comment: That can happen if `downloadAt` isn't defined in the model's schema. Can you add the schema definition to your question?

Comment: You are right! In my schema isn't defined `downloadAt`. Thanks!